# Ubuntu apt-get install for OracleJava 8 Installer - HTTP 501 error

Tags: java, ubuntu

I'm trying to install the Oracle Java 8 JDK on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine and it looks like the installer is broken -- I keep getting `ERROR 501: Redirected to invalid target`.

I'm on a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 so I ran the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

On the install, here is the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
oracle-java8-installer is already the newest version (8u171-1~webupd8~0).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-45 linux-headers-4.4.0-45-generic linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-45-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up oracle-java8-installer (8u171-1~webupd8~0) ...
Using wget settings from /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer/wgetrc
Downloading Oracle Java 8...
--2018-06-12 10:49:41--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u171-b11/512cd62ec5174c3487ac17c61aaa89e8/jdk-8u171-linux-x64.tar.gz
Connecting to 10.0.10.117:3142... connected.
Proxy request sent, awaiting response... 501 Redirected to invalid target
2018-06-12 10:49:41 ERROR 501: Redirected to invalid target.

download failed
Oracle JDK 8 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing package oracle-java8-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java8-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I get a 501 as well when I try to access that `http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u171-b11/512cd62ec5174c3487ac17c61aaa89e8/jdk-8u171-linux-x64.tar.gz` in a browser.  So anyone know a slick workaround?

Comment: Hmm, looking at it now, maybe I can modify the `wget` settings to pass a cookie or something?

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u171-b11/512cd62ec5174c3487ac17c61aaa89e8/jdk-8u171-linux-x64.tar.gz .... is not a valid link any more. The latest Oracle restrictions were : Say **yes** to the license. ( And the "ppa:webupd8team/java" has not been updated for some time.)

Comment: Are you using a proxy?